# Ember : Hook for css property change

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have to render a lot of divs into DOM. So, what I did is I render the first 5 elements into the DOM first after that I render every 10 divs with 300ms interval period.

The problem is when I change into `display: block` I need to change something in the component. So, I try to use `didRender` hook for that.

Code is below

```
didRender() {
   if(this.element.offsetParent) {
      this.set('myvar', true);
   }
}
```

But it's not working perfectly. Anyone please suggest me which is the best way to do this.

_Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you really need, you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Would be helpful if you add more about your use case. Your approach seems to be wrong to me but hard to advise another one without additional context. If it's about rendering a very large list of items without introducing performance issues, you might want to have a look at the addons existing to address that issue. E.g. [ember-collection](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-collection) and [ember-large-list](https://github.com/foxnewsnetwork/ember-large-list).

Comment: @jelhan Can you post the answer about the addons. Those kinds of working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to guess your use case from the question but I assume that it's about rendering a very large list of items without causing performance issues. The ember ecosystem provides bulletproofen addons to do so. The most established ones I'm aware of are [`ember-collection`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-collection) and [`ember-large-list`](https://github.com/foxnewsnetwork/ember-large-list). I would recommend to use one of these if they suit your requirements. Reimplementing something similar will be a lot of work. Rendering new items on a timeout basis would not scale well as it doesn't take workload of browser into account.

For your concrete question: Ember does not provide a way to listen to CSS changes. You should execute custom logic at the same place as in which you are mutating the property which triggers the CSS change. If it has to be run after render, you need to deal with Ember's [runloop](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/run-loop/).